# ¿Cómo leer un archivo .zip desde una url?

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy intentando leer desde una url el contenido de un archivo `.zip` en `python3`, el archivo contiene en su interior una carpeta y dentro de la carpeta hay imágenes. el código que he intentado es el siguiente:

```
urivisV2="http://iris.di.ubi.pt/ubiris2_1.zip"
zip1= pd.read_csv(urivisV2)
```

pero me sale este error:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 1 urivisV2="http://iris.di.ubi.pt/ubiris2_1.zip"
> ----> 2 zip1= pd.read_csv(urivisV2,compression='zip') #{'infer', 'gzip', 'bz2','zip' , 'xz', None}
> 3
>
> 4 frames /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py
> in **init**(self, src, **kwds)    1889         kwds["usecols"] =
> self.usecols    1890
> -> 1891         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)    1892         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols    1893
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
> pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.**cinit**()
>
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
> pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()
>
> ValueError: Multiple files found in compressed zip file
> ['CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S1_I1.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S1_I10.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S1_I11.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S1_I12.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S1_I13.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S1_I14.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S1_I15.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S1_I2.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S1_I3.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S1_I4.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S1_I5.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S1_I6.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S1_I7.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S1_I8.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S1_I9.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S2_I1.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S2_I10.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S2_I11.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S2_I12.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S2_I13.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S2_I14.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S2_I15.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S2_I2.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S2_I3.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S2_I4.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S2_I5.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S2_I6.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S2_I7.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S2_I8.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C100_S2_I9.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C101_S1_I1.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C101_S1_I10.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C101_S1_I11.tiff',
> 'CLASSES_400_300_Part1/C101_S1_I12.tiff', 'CLASSES_400_300_Par...

Comment: Bienvenida Estrella a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: ¿Por que estas leyendo con `read_csv` un archivo zip con imágenes? `read_csv` para leer datos desde archivos de tipo csv (separados por coma) nada tiene que ver con imagenes.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de abrir el archivo tienes que manejar el archivo zip, te recomiendo usar ZipFile. Algo así:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

pd.read_csv(zip_file.open('miArchivo.txt'))
```

Y si ocupas recorrer entre los archivos puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

zip = ZipFile(miArchivo)

misArchivos = zip.infolist()

for archivo in misArchivos:
    zip.read(archivo.filename)
```

Comment: Gracias, pero es abirlo desde esta url: http://iris.di.ubi.pt/ubiris2_1.zip